# dbt table coverage metric

Tags: data-warehouse, dbt

Given that I have a data warehouse with various tables being created from various sources many of them by dbt, I want to measure a concept like 'dbt table coverage' which I define as:

```
dtc = count(tables and views that exist) / count(non ephemeral models and sources)
```

This would be really useful in order to maintain a sense of quality/completeness, especially during transition projects. Is there a dbt command like:

```
dbt report table-coverage --schemas=['reporting','example']
>>> 96% coverage, 48/50 tables in the schemas provided are captured in dbt.
```

If not, how can we add this to the project?!

What alternate approaches could I take to solving the problem

Comment: Hey jabberwocky - can you also add your platform here? (snowflake, bigquery, etc.) Would be helpful to answering the question.

Comment: Sure. I'm actually running against sql-server using the adapter here - https://github.com/mikaelene/dbt-sqlserver, soon to switch over to Azure Synapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would probably create a model (view) that queried the information_schema and made some assumptions about a 1-to-1 mapping of `{sourceTableName}` to `stg_{sourceTableName}` (Assuming this means coverage for you).

Additionally I would look into using the `graph.sources.values()` JINJA function in order to iterate through all of the documented sources in your project, and then compare that with each of the models in `{target.schema}`

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/graph#accessing-sources

If you're comparing the existence of `source.schema.yml` with the `source.information_schema`. I would alter the approach to consider mapping each of the items in the graph against the total count of items in the information_schema on the source database.

Comment: Accepted this one as graph.sources.values() was the inspiration I needed, just used .nodes instead!

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts here since this is pretty intriguing to my current case as well:

1. dbt doesn't give outputs of queries or return a result to the command line. (That I know of!) So that if 1 inherently unsupported feature at this time. i.e. `dbt report` or `dbt query` doesn't exist yet. If that's desired, I'm recommend build out a feature request here:
   https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues
2. If you're ok with making a model in dbt and then just executing that via your client of choice, let's give that a shot. (I'm using postgres so convert accordingly)

   ```
   WITH schema_map as
      (select schemaname as schema,
       tablename as name,
       'Table' as Type,
       CASE WHEN schemaname like '%dbt%' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END as dbt_created
       from pg_tables
   WHERE NOT schemaname = ANY('{information_schema,pg_catalog}')
   UNION
   select schemaname as schema,
       viewname as name,
       'View' as Type,
       CASE WHEN schemaname like '%dbt%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END as dbt_created
       from pg_views
    WHERE NOT schemaname = ANY('{information_schema,pg_catalog}') )
    SELECT count(name) as total_tables_and_views,
       sum(dbt_created) as dbt_created,
       to_char((sum(dbt_created)::dec/count(name)::dec)*100,'999D99%') as dbt_coverage
    FROM schema_map
   ```

Gives the result:

```
total_tables_and_views | dbt_created | dbt_coverage
391                    |292          |  74.68%
```

Comment: This seems to be dependent on fully isolated schemas for dbt, which is not available in my use case.

Comment: Understood - do you have a dedicated dbt "user" that creates or owns the schemas / tables etc?

Comment: There's a specific user that creates the views/tables etc in the production environment... I couldn't guarantee that 0 tables have been created by users with --prod arg on CLI.   But could aim for it in future, it's a reasonable assumption. Schemas are not created by that same user (bolting dbt on back of existing setup at present)

Answer (score 0):

Just to feed back to the community and thanks to Jordan and Gscott for the inspiration. The solution I executed for SQL Server/ Synapse was:

1. A Daily execution of Counts of models in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and in the dbt graph as one table.
2. An incremental table built on 1 that selects schemas of interest and aggregates. In my case below I filter out staging and testing.

DbtModelCounts:

```
{% set models = [] -%}

{% if execute %}
  {% for node in graph.nodes.values()
    | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model")
    %}
        {%- do models.append(node.name) -%}

  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

with tables AS
(
SELECT table_catalog [db], table_schema [schema_name], table_name [name], table_type [type]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
),
dbt_tables AS
(
SELECT *
FROM tables
WHERE name in (
    {%- for model in models %}
    ('{{ model}}') 
    {% if not loop.last %},
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    )
)
SELECT
    tables.db, 
    tables.schema_name,
    tables.type,
    COUNT(tables.name) ModelCount,
    COUNT(dbt_tables.name) DbtModelCount
FROM tables
LEFT JOIN dbt_tables ON
    tables.name=dbt_tables.name AND
    tables.schema_name = dbt_tables.schema_name AND
    tables.db = dbt_tables.db AND 
    tables.type = dbt_tables.type
GROUP BY
    tables.db,
    tables.schema_name,
    tables.type
```

Dbt Coverage:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='DateCreated'
  )
}}
SELECT 
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DateCreated,
    GETDATE() AS DateTimeCreatedUTC,
    SUM(DbtModelCount) AS DbtModelCount, 
    SUM(ModelCount) AS TotalModels,
    SUM(DbtModelCount)*100.0/SUM(ModelCount) as DbtCoveragePercentage
FROM {{ref('DbtModelCounts')}}
WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'testing%' AND schema_name NOT LIKE 'staging%'
```

To do, add logic for defined sources to also compute percentage of sources that map to my staging or raw schema tables .